# How do I change a key's value to that of another key's value if the value is the name of another key?

Tags: python, dictionary

To explain what I mean, I'm adding keys and values to a dictionary but if a key in the dictionary has a value that's the name of another key, I want that key to be assigned the other key's value. For example, if I have `dict1 = {"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": "a"}`
is it possible to change the value of c to 100 (which is a's value)? So instead it would be
`dict1 = {"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": 100}` The code I have right now is obviously wrong and giving me an error but I was trying to type out what I thought would work

```
for x, y in dict1.items():
       if dict1[x] == dict1[x]:
           dict1[x] = dict1[y]
       print(x, y)
```

Comment: Seems like the order is important. What is the expected result if the dict is `d = {"a": "c", "b": 200, "c": "b"}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
my_dict = {"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": "a"}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if v in my_dict:
        my_dict[k] = my_dict[v]
```

You can alternatively use a dict comprehension:

```
result = {
    k: my_dict[v] if v in my_dict else v
    for k, v in my_dict.items()
}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 100}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, if I'm putting user input from an html form into a python dictionary, how would I make "c" : "a" into "c" : 100 instead of "c" : "a"? I just discovered the html form is all string and when I do int(value) on it, of course it doesn't work since "a" is a letter

Comment: You might want to open a new question and post some more context code.  You could try using a try/except block: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions